# How to connect with linux server from mobile app without ppk file?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

i have created a linux instance in AWS. Now it is working fine with putty. But i have to connect it with my won mobile application from both IOS and Android. My problem is in putty i will be having .ppk file for authentication so by including this file i can connect with desired linux server. But from mobile application i don't any option to include this file.. I can give Hostname, Port No, SSH, Username, Password.. I don't have any idea about it

Is it possible to connect from mobile application to linux server without .ppk file ?? Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Are you developing a mobile application? Or is this about some existing mobile application that you want to use? The latter is off-topic here.

Comment: It is a existing mobile application.. i am try to use it

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Though @Paul gave you the answer already. Some applications do support keys. E.g. iSSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but keys are good.

Now the ppk file is essentially just for putty. Most other SSH clients will accept the pem without converting it to the ppk. 
[Terminus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.server.auditor.ssh.client&hl=en), for example, will accept the pem key and allow you to login with it just fine.

But, if you really want to login without a key, just run:

```
$ sudo adduser remote-login-username
```

And you should then be able to use that account without a key

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But i have our own mobile application.. I want to connect with that..

Comment: then do that^ Add a new user, give it a password, and it won't need a key.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an app like webssh you can paste in the content of that ppk file. Easiest way is open the ppk in notepad and email it on your mobile device then copy and paste into the private key field in the ssh app.